# Rails: one attribute will only update in console, not in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple Rails app to represent people in an office - each person has a name, email, desk number, etc.

My problem is definitely something simple I've overlooked - when I create a new person and give them a desk number, or update an existing person to change the desk number using the app in the browser, the change isn't taken into account - I can only update the desk number in the console.

I added the 'desk' attribute separately as an afterthought rather than at the time of creating 'person', so I'm thinking there's something I've missed there.

**show.html.haml:**

```
%h1
  = @person.name

.row
  .span4.avatar-placeholder
    %p [photo coming soon...]

  .span8
    %table{class: 'table table-striped'}
      %tbody
        %tr
          %th Name
          %td
            = @person.name
        %tr
          %th Position
          %td
            = @person.position
        %tr
          %th Email
          %td
            = @person.email
        %tr
          %th Irc
          %td
            = @person.irc
        %tr
          %th Desk
          %td
            =@person.desk
```

All elements here update fine apart from 'desk'.

**schema.db**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131104165816) do

  create_table "people", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "photo"
    t.string   "position"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "irc"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.integer  "desk"
  end
end
```

And I have nothing really in the **person.rb** model yet:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

*Sample scenario 1 :*

- I go to /people/new, fill out all the fields, and submit
- I'm redirected to /people/3. Name, Position, Email and Irc are all shown as I entered them into the form, but Desk displayed nothing. Further investigation shows desk is set to 'nil'.

*Sample scenario 2 :*

- In rails console, I do:

  > > p = Person.find_by(id:2)
  > >
  > > p.update_attribute :desk, 10
- I go to /people/2, and the desk number is successfully displayed as 10.

---

Have I included all necessary information there? Thanks to anyone who can help!

**Edit - controller.rb:**

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /people
  # GET /people.json
  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  # GET /people/1
  # GET /people/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /people/new
  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  # GET /people/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /people
  # POST /people.json
  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /people/1
  # PATCH/PUT /people/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /people/1
  # DELETE /people/1.json
  def destroy
    @person.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to people_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_person
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :photo, :position, :email, :irc)
    end
end
```

**form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for(@person, :html => {:multipart => true, class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|
  - if @person.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this person from being saved:
      %ul
        - @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .box
    .form-inputs
      = f.input :name
      = f.input :photo
      = f.input :position
      = f.input :email
      = f.input :irc
      = f.input :desk

  .form-actions.well
    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success'
    = link_to 'Back', people_path, class: 'btn'
```

Comment: Please add the controller code

Comment: As well as the form code. The code of `show` action is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Controller and form code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put `desk` in your permitted parameters:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :photo, :position, :email, :irc, :desk)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised I needed to update my person_params if I added an extra attribute!

Comment: @Marek Lipka Nice spot! I thought Rails threw an error if you tried to create/update a record and didn't specify one of the attributes in the accepted parameters. Does it just put it in the server log as a warning?